# Javascript changes all image title attributes and not just the selected img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension which allows people to report child sexual abuse images they find online. As soon as they report the image it should be replaced with another that is part of the extension. This all works well.

We also change the href of the image, the title and the alt.
This is where things go wrong. The code is like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for(var idx = 0; idx < imgs.length; idx ++)
  {
    // request.greeting = an img src url
    if(imgs[idx].src == request.greeting) 
    {      
      var width = imgs[idx].getAttribute("width");
      var height = imgs[idx].height;
      var st = imgs[idx].style;

          imgs[idx].src = imgURL;  // Change the Image and set it's properties                   
          imgs[idx].href = "http:\\7ASecond.Net";
          imgs[idx].alt = "Removed by 7ASecond.Net";
          imgs[idx].title = "Removed by 7ASecond.Net";
          resizeImg(imgs[idx]);
         // imgs[idx].setAttribute("style", "width=" + width + "; height=" + height + ";");
        }
      }
    }

  });
```

What actually happens is that all images on the page have their title, and alt changed. Can you see the problem? Do you want to join the team to make this most needed extension? :D

The Image Src is sent from the background page using a message - the code for that looks like this:

```
if(info.mediaType === "image")
{
  sUrl = encodeURI(info.srcUrl);
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: sUrl}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping in the first place, shouldn't you have a reference to the image object?

Comment: @epascarello Added partial background page code to show what is being sent. But I think you may have a point - I am very new to Javascript so - just kind of feeling my way

Comment: And not all images are image tags.

Comment: @epascarello Ok so I passed the whole image object to the content script but now it says I cannot get the image width or size from the object!

Comment: Your loop is kinda okay so the only explanation why it changes all images  is that your background script is incorrectly sending requests for all the images. Include the relevant part of background.js in your question or link it via pastebin/similar services.

Comment: I did - it is the last part of the code - all that is sent is the srcUrl... it could be some kinda stupidity on Google Images.